# Parse Cloud Code with Swift & Stripe: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_each'

Tags: swift, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to use cloud code with stripe, but I am getting an error from the cloud code file:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_each'
    at request (stripe.js:58:11)
    at post (stripe.js:117:12)
    at Object.module.exports.Charges.create (stripe.js:157:16)
    at main.js:7:18 (Code: 141, Version: 1.8.2)
Charge not working
Optional("Hello world!")
```

Here is the cloud code .js file:

```
var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize(MYKEY);

Parse.Cloud.define("charge", function(request, response) {


  Stripe.Charges.create({
    source: request.params.token,
    amount: request.params.amount,
    currency: "usd"
  },{
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        response.success("Purchase made!");
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
        response.error("Error: "+httpResponse.message+"\n"+
               "Params:\n"+
               request.params.token+","+
               request.params.amount+
               "\n"
              );
    }
  });
});


Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
  response.success("Hello world!");
});
```

I am calling the cloud code from a view controller with Swift:

```
        let card = STPCard()
        card.number = stripeCreditCardInput.card?.number
        card.expMonth = (stripeCreditCardInput.card?.expMonth)!
        card.expYear = (stripeCreditCardInput.card?.expYear)!
        card.cvc = stripeCreditCardInput.card?.cvc

        STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithCard(card, completion: { (token, stripeError) -> Void in
            if stripeError != nil {
                self.handleError(stripeError!)
            } else {
                print("Your token is: \(token!)")

                if let myToken = token?.tokenId {

                    let amount = 1000 * 3.5

                    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", withParameters: nil) {
                        (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        let responseString = response as? String
                        print(responseString)
                    }

                    //let name = PFUser.currentUser()?.username as String!

                    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("charge", withParameters: ["token" : myToken, "amount": amount], block: { (success: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("Charge not working")
                        }
                    })

                }

            }
        })
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

So here is the confirmed fix,
just type this into the console

```
jssdk 1.5.0
```

it reverts your SDK version 1.5.0 which works fine, something is messed up in latest version of sdk and the documentation is broken also.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem after updating my Cloud Code version today. If you find a fix, please post it here, need it desperately.

Comment: I have the same problem... Also I noticed Parse's Stripe library link is broken... Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @lbdakine I temporarily fixed it by using an older version of cloud code. Version 1.3.5 works fine.

Comment: wow thank you for the quick reply @Florian. How do I revert to an old version of cloud code?

Comment: I found it via Parse documentation. If anyone else is looking for this, here is is, just type this into the console: parse jssdk 1.5.0 to revert to 1.5.0. Thank you @Florian!

Comment: @lbdakine nice find, at least I can upgrade to 1.5.0 then. You're welcome, I was lucky I had an old version of the cloud code as a copy

Comment: does your code charge a customer or just a token? For some reason, when I charge a customer with something like customer: customer.id I'm getting an error. I'm thinking it might have something to do with 1.5.0 but not sure. I haven't had time to revert back to versions less than 1.5.0. Let me know. Thanks!